# Why my computer beeps while using String(char[]ch) code?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I am using JCreator,it compiles fine but beeps while running the code

```
class StringDemo {

public static void main(String[]args){

    char[]arr={7};

    String s1= new String(arr);
    System.out.println(s1); //prints nothing

  }
}
```

Comment: That specific character must make a noise :)

Comment: Not necessarily. On my laptop it just prints the Unicode replacment character � with no sound.

Comment: try `char[] arr = {'7'};`

Comment: `System.out.println("\u0007");` if you want to use beep more often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ascii/Unicode character 7 is the ['bell' code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character). As such, when you print it, the console is configured to generate a sound.

Comment: well ! I had never thought of it. Thanks a lot.